# Magmi - several configuration files for databases informations

Tags: magmi

I'm trying to set several profiles on my Magmi to import products into several websites.
In the conf/ folder I have one sub folder for each website, it works fine for each profiles configuration.

I would like to know if it is possible or not to configure global parameters differently for each websites ?

I know that they are "global" parameters but I have several databases with different connectivity informations, and I would like that each time that a profile is selected, the database informations also change.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  Magmi was designed to be configured to one Magento database, not multiple.

To make it work the way you want it would require customizing Magmi itself.

Answer (score 0):

As you can install as many Magmi you want under separate directories, it could be a workaround about your problem.
Each Magmi could be configured with a different set of global parameters.
I regularly use such a configuration to have at least 2 operational Magmi versions :

- a directory with a proven Magmi version
- an other directory with a new Magmi version to test